# App.xaml.cs Startup Code Refactoring

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Quite simply, this is my base class for Xamarin forms, everything is fully working, but it's getting a bit too long and feels a bit like it can be improved, especially the network bit could be handled differently.

Anyone have any idea how I can split this up?

```
/// <summary> The startup class for the cross-platform project </summary>
    public partial class App
    {
        /// <summary> The container for all our dependency injections.  </summary>
        private static TinyIoCContainer _container;

        /// <summary> Handles pop up and other alerts </summary>
        private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

        public static Double ScreenHeight { get; set; }
        public static Double ScreenWidth { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="App" /> class.
        ///     This is the start up method of the entire application along with it's corresponding start up method in the native
        ///     platform.
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Register for connectivity changes, be sure to unsubscribe when finished
            Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += ConnectivityChanged;

            // Enables Experimental features
            Device.SetFlags(new[] {"Markup_Experimental", "Brush_Experimental", "Shapes_Experimental"});

            // Retrieve token
            var token = GetTokenAsync().Result;
#if DEBUG
            EnableDebugRainbows(false);
            RegisterDependencies(true);
            GlobalSetting.Instance.UpdateRunMode(true, token);
#else
            RegisterDependencies(false);
            GlobalSetting.Instance.UpdateRunMode(true, token);
#endif

            _dialogService = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IDialogService>();

            // Start navigation, do this last
            InitNavigation();

            SetDeviceHeightAndWidth();
        }

        private void SetDeviceHeightAndWidth()
        {
            // Get Metrics
            var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

            // Width (in pixels)
            var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
            // Width (in xamarin.forms units)
            var xamarinWidth = width / mainDisplayInfo.Density;
            // Height (in pixels)
            var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
            // Screen density
            var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;

            ScreenWidth = xamarinWidth;
        }

        /// <summary> Called when the application starts. </summary>
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Initialize AppCenter
            AppCenter.Start(
                """,
                typeof(Analytics),
                typeof(Crashes));
        }

        /// <summary> Gets the token from secure storage in app </summary>
        /// <returns> returns token as a string </returns>
        private static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var oauthToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("AuthAccessToken").ConfigureAwait(false);
                return oauthToken;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Applies Debug Coloring to UI if enabled </summary>
        private void EnableDebugRainbows(bool shouldUseDebugRainbows)
        {
            Resources.Add(new Style(typeof(ContentPage))
            {
                ApplyToDerivedTypes = true, Setters = {new Setter {Property = DebugRainbow.ShowColorsProperty, Value = shouldUseDebugRainbows}}
            });
        }

        /// <summary> Registers our dependency services. </summary>
        public static void RegisterDependencies(bool inDebugMode)
        {
            // 1. Create a new Tiny Ioc container
            _container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;

            // 2. Register Services - by default, TinyIoC will register interface registrations as singletons.
            _container.Register<IRequestProvider, RequestProvider>();
            _container.Register<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
            _container.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
            _container.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();

            if (inDebugMode)
            {
                _container.Register<IFormsService, FormsMockService>();
                _container.Register<IJobsService, JobsMockService>();
                _container.Register<IMediaService, MediaFileMockService>();

                GlobalSetting.InDebugMode = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _container.Register<IFormsService, FormService>();
                _container.Register<IJobsService, JobsService>();
                _container.Register<IMediaService, MediaFileService>();

                GlobalSetting.InDebugMode = false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Decides where user will be redirected to, if logged in already skip login. </summary>
        private void InitNavigation()
        {
            var navigationHelper = new ShellNavigationHelper();

            var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            navigationHelper.RegisterViewsInAssembly(currentAssembly);

            TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register<INavigationHelper>(navigationHelper);

            foreach (var type in currentAssembly.ExportedTypes.Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ViewModelBase))))
            {
                TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register(type);
            }

            foreach (var type in currentAssembly.ExportedTypes.Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Page))))
            {
                TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register(type);
            }

            Resolver.SetResolver(new TinyIoCResolver());

            var token = GlobalSetting.Instance.AuthToken;

            // If no token go to login page, else go to main page
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                MainPage = new LoginPage();
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new AppShell();
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Called when the application is resumed, after being sent to the background. </summary>
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += ConnectivityChanged;
        }

        /// <summary> Called each time the application goes to the background. </summary>
        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= ConnectivityChanged;
        }

        /// <summary> Show a toast at bottom when connectivity is lost </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">  The sender. </param>
        /// <param name="eventArgs">  The eventArgs hold the connectivity information </param>
        private void ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var access = eventArgs.NetworkAccess;
            var netStatus = CheckNetAccess(access);

            _dialogService.ShowAlertAsync(netStatus, "Internet", "OK");

            var profiles = eventArgs.ConnectionProfiles;
            var internetType = CheckInternetType(profiles);

            _dialogService.ShowAlertAsync(internetType, "Internet Type", "OK");
        }

        private static string CheckInternetType(IEnumerable<ConnectionProfile> profiles)
        {
            var connectionProfiles = profiles.ToList();
            return connectionProfiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi)
                ? connectionProfiles.FirstOrDefault().ToString()
                : "No Wifi";
        }

        private static string CheckNetAccess(NetworkAccess access)
        {
            return access switch
            {
                NetworkAccess.Internet => "Local and internet access",
                NetworkAccess.Local => "Local network access only",
                NetworkAccess.ConstrainedInternet => "Limited internet access",
                NetworkAccess.None => "No connectivity is available",
                NetworkAccess.Unknown => "Unable to determine internet connectivity",
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(access), access, null)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Re-entrance

I don't think that these:

```
        private static TinyIoCContainer _container;
        public static Double ScreenHeight { get; set; }
        public static Double ScreenWidth { get; set; }
```

should be static. Particularly for the purposes of unit testing, these should simply be instance properties on your `App`. The feasibility of this might be limited by an external contract for `RegisterDependencies` that I don't understand, mind you.

### Implicit types

`var` is over-used, here. The usual policy I recommend is that - if a type is obvious, such as the case of an object being constructed and then assigned, `var` is fine; like this:

```
var navigationHelper = new ShellNavigationHelper();
```

But, for something like this:

```
var netStatus = CheckNetAccess(access);
```

Can you tell, just by looking at this line, the type of `netStatus`? No. Part of self-documenting code is making this more legible to others, and to yourself in a few weeks, by adding explicit types. An added benefit is that it will catch a certain category of regressions if the expected type changes.

Comment: I was thinking more in line of how to split up the networking code and didn't even consider those improvements, thanks!